# How to correctly structure Navigation in SwiftUI with custom UI and programmatic navigation?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swift5

I'm working on an app in `SwiftUI` where I use multiple views. My app's settings view uses a custom UI with buttons for navigation instead of a `List`. I was previously using `NavigationView`, but due to depreciation, I switched to using `NavigationStack`. I'm unsure if I've implemented this correctly.

The hierarchy of my app is as follows:

Dashboard > App Settings > Account Settings > Change Information > Name/Email/Phone/Password/... > CHANGE Information View.

In the settings part of my app, the root is the "App Settings" view, which contains various other settings views like "Account Settings". Some views need to change programmatically after a function runs, so I can't use `NavigationLink` for my buttons.

Here's an example of my current structure:

Settings View:

```
Button(action: {
    print("user pressed")
}, label: {
    NavigationLink(destination: {
        SettingsProfileView()
    }, label: {
        // UI code omitted for brevity
    })
})
```

Account Settings View:

```
Button(action: {
    print("Age Restriction Pressed")
    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)) {
    }
}, label: {
    NavigationLink(destination: {
        AccountInfoSubView()
    }, label: {
        // UI code omitted for brevity
    })
})
```

The problem I'm having is with the "Verify Current Password" view which verifies the user's current password before they can change it. After the user changes their password and clicks save, it's supposed to go back to the previous view. However, it seems like the .navigationDestination isn't recognizing that when isPresented is no longer true, it doesn't return to the previous view.

Verify Current Password View:

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing:
    Button(action: {
        isPresented = true
    }) {
        Text("Next")
            .foregroundColor(UserValidate().isPasswordValid(textField) ? .orange : .gray)
    }
    .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isPresented, destination: {
        PasswordChangeView(isPresented: $isPresented)
    })
)
.preferredColorScheme(.dark)
.padding()
```

And finally, the "Change Account Password" view:

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
    isPresented = false
}))
```

This last view isn't returning to the previous view, even though isPresented is now false. How can I properly structure my navigation so that my views behave as expected?

Comment: navigationBarItems Was deprecated 2 or 3 os versions ago there is no reason to use it with the newest tools such as NavigationStack and navigationDestination

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using the old bad way to set destination on your navigation flow.

- First: Define your navigationLink and for each link set the value
  which gonna be as a key. (you can write an enum for that)
- Second: In a wrapper put your navigation destination  read that enum and return the view you want to show

> ```
> NavigationStack {
>     List {
>         NavigationLink("Mint", value: Color.mint)
>         NavigationLink("Pink", value: Color.pink)
>         NavigationLink("Teal", value: Color.teal)
>     }
>     .navigationDestination(for: Color.self) { color in
>         ColorDetail(color: color)
>     }
>     .navigationTitle("Colors")
> ```

I will share with you a post and a video where is explained better.

https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/navigationlink-programmatically-binding/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=piAiy5vlC9k&t=3566s&ab_channel=KarinPrater